# Prevent / stop encoding the value of textarea while storing to database

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have one text area. When I enter html code in it and save the data, it is encoding automatically and adding `&lt; &gt; &nbsp;` etc.

How can I prevent this and store my data in database without encoding. If I access same data, I would like it to display or be retreived without encoding or decoding.

```
 function SaveEmailContentData() {

     var emailTemplate = $("#textareaEmailHtmlContent").val();        
     var emailCategoryID =parseInt($("#ddlSelectCorpSearch").val());
     var corporateId = ClientID;
     var TemplateId = 0;
     if ('@Model.TemplateID' != 'null' && '@Model.TemplateID' != '0') {

         TemplateId = parseInt('@Model.TemplateID');

     }

     $.ajax({
         url: '../../Setup/Setup/SaveEmailContent',
         dataType: 'json',
         type: 'POST',
         data: JSON.stringify({ EmailContent: emailTemplate,EmailContentID:emailCategoryID, ClientID: corporateId, TempID: TemplateId }),
         cache: false,
         contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
         success: function (result) {
             debugger;
             if (result == "success") {
                 showMessage("Update Successful", "Email Content Successfully Updated");
             }
             else {
                 showMessage("Update Failed", "Email Content could not be Updated");
             }
         },
         error: function () {

             alert("error");
         }
     });
 }
```

Comment: add `SaveEmailContent` action code in your code.

Comment: when i trace here, in this page only in  "emailTemplate" i am getting that encoded code before passing to SaveEmailContent. After passing data to action method, there also save encoded value is recieved

Comment: is it possible to prevent that encoding in this page only before passing to action method .